# Некорректно читаются CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, proxy

Я новичок, поэтому не особо понимаю, в чем может быть проблема. Использую Python 3.6., пробовала работать и с Анакондой, и с PyCharm, проблема аналогичная- CSV файлы читаются некорректно

```
File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 881, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 896, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 950, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 937, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2132, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 55 fields in line 1339, saw 59
```

Думала проблема в том, что старый Pandas. PyCharm не дает обновить выше 0.25, может это связано с тем, что я через рабочий Proxy

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/pandas/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas==1.2.4 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas==1.2.4
```

При этом некоторые другие пакеты обновляет. В Anaconda стоит Pandas новой версии, а файлы все равно читаются с аналогичными ошибками.

Comment: Поясните, что вы имеете ввиду, когда говорите, что файл читается, но читается некорректно?  Покажите выделенный фрагмент кода, в котором вы читаете что-то из файла, и  при выполнении которого происходит ошибка. И второе -  по правилу этого форума "Один вопрос -  одна проблема". Поэтому вопрос про неустанавливаемую Pandas удалите в этом вопросе и перенесите в другой -  пока вопрос не закрыли.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, я упомянула про Pandas так как возможно это связано с проблемой некорректного чтения файлов. Когда говорю про некорректно, имею ввиду, что он выдает ошибку (фрагмент ошибки - первый код в вопросе). Когда добавляю error_bad_lines и пропускаю ошибку- вижу, что файл прочтен неправильно- сьехали столбцы, все данные могут быть в первом, а могут быть частично рспределены по другим и прочее.

Comment: В подобных вопросах необходимо приводить небольшой __воспроизводимый__ пример данных, иначе этот вопрос не принесет пользы ни вам ни кому-либо еще

Answer (score 0):

Чаще всего проблема в разделителе. Попробуйте открыть файл в Excel и посмотреть чем разделяются значения. После этого попробуйте явно указать разделитель, например:

```
 pandas.read_csv(path, sep = ';')
```